# Make soap xml with encoding/xml package in Golang

Tags: xml, go

I want to make a sample xml that repeats a field depending on the value of the slice. But the final result is not as desired.

**XML that I want to create**

```
        recipients = ["num1","num2",...]

        //Start XML
        .
        .
        .
        <SendDetail>
            <item><Mobile>num1</Mobile></item>
            <item><Mobile>num2</Mobile></item>
            ...
        </SendDetail>
```

The number of repetitions of  depends on the length of the slice of recipients and its values.

**My Code**

```
        type item struct {
            Mobile  []string `xml:"Mobile"`
        }
        type sendDetail struct {
            Item *[]item `xml:"item"`
        }   


        SendDetail: &sendDetail{
                Item:&[]item{
                    item{
                        Mobile:recipients,
                    },
                },
            },
```

**Result**

```
      <SendDetail>
        <item>
          <Mobile>num1</Mobile>
          <Mobile>num2</Mobile>
        </item>
      </SendDetail>
```

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you want item.Mobile to be a string, not a string slice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your XML inside an `<item>` there is only a single `<Mobile>` tag. You don't want to repeat the `<Mobile>` tag but the `<item>` tag. So in Go you have to create a new `Item` for each number.

Model it like this:

```
type Item struct {
    Mobile string `xml:"Mobile"`
}

type SendDetail struct {
    Items []*Item `xml:"item"`
}
```

Example using the model:

```
recipients := []string{"num1", "num2"}

sd := &SendDetail{}
for _, recipient := range recipients {
    sd.Items = append(sd.Items, &Item{Mobile: recipient})
}

data, err := xml.MarshalIndent(sd, "", "  ")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(string(data))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MXHyGWr-O-I)):

```
<SendDetail>
  <item>
    <Mobile>num1</Mobile>
  </item>
  <item>
    <Mobile>num2</Mobile>
  </item>
</SendDetail>
```